# Can a wizard cast the same spell twice simultaneously?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

Could a wizard cast the same spell (utility, non-combat [Tiny Servant]) twice at the same time? Using, obviously, both slots, just dual-cast to save a minute or two? I assume the Somatic components for this spell are part of the touching, and there are no material components.

Example:
Blog-hart the Red wishes to re-enact the original Fantasia's Magician's Apprentice. One minute per broom seems too long to him, so he grabs two, and attempts to cast Tiny Servant twice at the same time.

Comment: Note that you can achieve this particular result by casting _tiny servant_ using a higher level slot to animate multiple items. This is specific to that spell, though, not a general case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## No.

Each spell has a casting time, during which you can perform no other Action. Casting another spell, even the same one, would be another Action. Please see Player's Handbook chapter 9 for how actions work, and chapter 10 for how spellcasting works.

There are exceptions to the general rules, such as a sorcerer metamagic option called Twinned Spell, and the fighter's Action Surge that can allow a character to do similar things to what you described, but neither apply to your described situation.

Comment: Might add another exception that the only kind of spell that can be cast twice in the same turn is a cantrip.  Of course, requiring haste or action surge.

Comment: Thank you. I thought not, but I wanted another opinion.

Comment: @GcL: That is not true. If you cast a bonus-action spell on your turn, the only other spell you can cast on your turn is a cantrip. Otherwise, there is no restriction on the number or level of spells you can cast on your turn. (For instance, you can cast *fireball*, then use Action Surge and cast *fireball* again - or you can cast *fireball*, then an enemy might *counterspell* you, and you can cast *counterspell* to stop their counterspell and allow your fireball to take effect.)

Comment: I should note that you can use your reaction to cast a spell while already casting a spell. For example, if an enemy tries to counterspell your spell you can counterspell their counterspell and, if it succeeds, continue casting your spell.

Comment: *"Please see Player's Handbook chapter 9 for how actions work"* — Chapter 9 is called "Combat", isn't it? Eric asks about a non-combat situation specifically.

Comment: @enkryptor, yes, but it is the best source for the definition of capital-A Action.